# Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared after mysqltuner

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

My application logs show "Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared" after running mysqltuner ( bother version 1.1 and 1.4 ).  Once I run "flush tables;", the error goes away.  I have looked online and most things mention mysqldump in relation to this error, but I am not running mysqldump.  Not really doing anything, in fact.  So a few questions related to this error:

1. Any causes to this that are not related to mysqldump, generally speaking?
2. Anyone else have this problem with mysqltuner?
3. Does this suggest a deeper issue I need to look into?

my.conf:

```
[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#  NOTE:  server did not like over 2GB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1GB
innodb_log_buffer_size=9M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
#  join_buffer_size = 128M
join_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

lower_case_table_names=1

character-set-server=utf8
query_cache_size=100M
query_cache_type=1
slow_query_log=ON
query_cache_limit = 10M
table_open_cache=164000
open_files_limit=328000

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Tell me if you need other information.

Edit 03/10/2015:
I just did the following with no problems:

1. Ran mysqldump to dump one database ( fully, with data and functions ) to "loadDB.sql" script for later use.
2. Added new database
3. Using "mysql < loadDB.sql", loaded my new database
4. Updated and added rows to my new database
   I did not have any problems with the above.

So I only have a problem if I run mysqltuner.  What I don't know is if

1. mysqltuner is causing the problem, in which case I just either don't run mysqltuner ever, or immediately run "flush tables;" afterwards.
2. there is a problem with my mysql configuration, which will cause me problems later and needs to be resolved.
3. or there is some other problem source I have not considered yet
   The first step, and the reason for this post, is to determine if mysqltuner could cause this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any prepared statements in your procedures?

Comment: Probably.  It is buried in C code, via ODBC.  My concern is that everything seems fine until I run mysqltuner.  After that, things break and stay broken until I run "flush tables;".  I just don't understand how mysqltuner could influence things so much.

Comment: Ok, checking one case, we definitely have a prepare in the ODBC based code, but the select involved is super simpler, and is limited to 1 row: SELECT 1 FROM mbo USE INDEX(mbo_mbodock) WHERE mbosts = ? AND WHMSLayer_IS_LOC_ACCESSIBLE( ?, ?, mbodoc ) > 0 ORDER BY mbosts LIMIT 1.

Comment: Can you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873883/general-error-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared) and try to increase the value of mentioned variables?

Comment: First reply:  my table_open_cache is considerably bigger than the suggestion in that post.  But I did not change table_definition_cache, so I suppose I could try that.  All that said, that post says it still happens sometimes.  I see no evidence that he actually solved the problem.  Do you know different?

Answer (score 0):

mysqltuner is not running any FLUSH command at all in the code.

I have checked it in the last 1.5.1 version.