# Laravel: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I'm using last version of laravel (5.1) in a homestead virtual machine (vagrant).

I connect my project to a local mariaDB server, in which I have some table and 2 db-view.

Since I made some select only on the db-view tables, I receive back randomly this error:

> General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

From today, I always get this error when made select only on the db views.
If I open my phpMyAdmin and make the same select it return the correct result.

I tried to open `php artisan tinker` and select one record of the db-view but it return the same error:

```
// Select one user from user table
>>> $user = new App\User
=> <App\User #000000006dc32a890000000129f667d2> {}
>>> $user = App\User::find(1);
=> <App\User #000000006dc32a9e0000000129f667d2> {
       id: 1,
       name: "Luca",
       email: "luca@email.it",
       customerId: 1,
       created_at: "2015-08-06 04:17:57",
       updated_at: "2015-08-11 12:39:01"
   }
>>> 
// Select one source from Source db-view
>>> $source = new App\Source
=> <App\Source #000000006dc32a820000000129f667d2> {}
>>> $source = App\Source::find(1);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from `sources` where `sources`.`id` = 1 limit 1)'
```

How can I fix that?
I read about a problem with mysqldump (but not in my case) and to increase value of `table_definition_cache` but it is not sure that it will work and I can't modify them.

Is this a kind of laravel bug?

How can I figure that out?

---

Edit:

As asked, I add my model source code.
Source.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Source extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sources';


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FOREIGN KEYS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * 
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function customersList(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\CustomerSource", "sourceId", "id");
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function issues(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Issue", "sourceId", "id");
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2:

If I execute the same query in the project with mysqli it works:

```
$db = new mysqli(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USERNAME'), getenv('DB_PASSWORD'), getenv('DB_DATABASE'));
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    dd('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sources` WHERE `id` = 4";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    dd('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

dd($result->fetch_assoc());
```

---

EDIT 3:
Afeter 2 month, I'm still there. Same error and no solution found.
I decide to try a little solution in aritsan tinker but no good news.
I report what I've tried:

First try to fetch a table model:

```
>>> $user = \App\User::find(1);
=> App\User {#697
     id: 1,
     name: "Luca",
     email: "luca.d@company.it",
     customerId: 1,
     created_at: "2015-08-06 04:17:57",
     updated_at: "2015-10-27 11:28:14",
   }
```

Now try to fetch a view table model:

```
>>> $ir = \App\ContentRepository::find(15);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.content_repositories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `content_repositories` where `content_repositories`.`id` = 1 limit 1)'
```

When contentRepository doesn't have correct table name setup inside the model ContentRepository.php:

```
>>> $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
=> PDO {#690
     inTransaction: false,
     errorInfo: [
       "00000",
       1146,
       "Table 'dbname.content_repositories' doesn't exist",
     ],
     attributes: [
       "CASE" => NATURAL,
       "ERRMODE" => EXCEPTION,
       "AUTOCOMMIT" => 1,
       "PERSISTENT" => false,
       "DRIVER_NAME" => "mysql",
       "SERVER_INFO" => "Uptime: 2513397  Threads: 12  Questions: 85115742  Slow queries: 6893568  Opens: 1596  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 936  Queries per second avg: 33.864",
       "ORACLE_NULLS" => NATURAL,
       "CLIENT_VERSION" => "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: id_here $",
       "SERVER_VERSION" => "5.5.5-10.0.17-MariaDB-1~wheezy-wsrep-log",
       "STATEMENT_CLASS" => [
         "PDOStatement",
       ],
       "EMULATE_PREPARES" => 0,
       "CONNECTION_STATUS" => "localiphere via TCP/IP",
       "DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE" => BOTH,
     ],
   }
>>>
```

CHANGE TABLE VALUE INSIDE model ContentRepository.php:

```
>>> $ir = \App\ContentRepository::find(15);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from `contentRepository` where `contentRepository`.`id` = 15 limit 1)'
```

When it is correct, **pay attention to "errorInfo" that is missing**:

```
>>> $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
=> PDO {#690
     inTransaction: false,
     attributes: [
       "CASE" => NATURAL,
       "ERRMODE" => EXCEPTION,
       "AUTOCOMMIT" => 1,
       "PERSISTENT" => false,
       "DRIVER_NAME" => "mysql",
       "SERVER_INFO" => "Uptime: 2589441  Threads: 13  Questions: 89348013  Slow queries: 7258017  Opens: 1604  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 943  Queries per second avg: 34.504",
       "ORACLE_NULLS" => NATURAL,
       "CLIENT_VERSION" => "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: id_here $",
       "SERVER_VERSION" => "5.5.5-10.0.17-MariaDB-1~wheezy-wsrep-log",
       "STATEMENT_CLASS" => [
         "PDOStatement",
       ],
       "EMULATE_PREPARES" => 0,
       "CONNECTION_STATUS" => "localIPhere via TCP/IP",
       "DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE" => BOTH,
     ],
   }
```

Show db's tables:

```
>>> $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
=> [
     {#702
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there",
     },
     {#683
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there",
     },
     {#699
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there",
     },
     {#701
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there-20150917-1159",
     },
     {#704
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "contentRepository", */ VIEW TABLE IS THERE!!!! /*
     },
     {#707
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there",
     },
     {#684
       +"Tables_in_dbname": "table_name_there",
     },
   ]
```

Try with normal select:

```
>>> $results = DB::select('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1');
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1)'
```

Try unprepared query:

```
>>> DB::unprepared('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1')
=> false
```

Try second time unprepared query:

```
>>> DB::unprepared('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1')
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1)'
```

Try PDOStatement::fetchAll():

```
>>> DB::fetchAll('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1'); 
PHP warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'fetchAll' in /Users/luca/company/Laravel/dbname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php on line 296
```

Try second PDOStatement::fetchAll():

```
>>> $pdo::fetchAll('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1');
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()
```

Try statement... :

```
>>> $pdos = DB::statement('select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1')
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from dbname.contentRepository limit 1)'
```

Thank you

Comment: Add your Source model, please.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It seems to work adding

```
'options'   => [
                \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            ]
```

Inside `projectName/config/database.php` file in DB configuration. It will be like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'options'   => [
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    ]
],
```

Laravel 5.1. Hope it will help!

**Edit:**
I'm currently on **Laravel 8** and this solution is still working.

Comment: Note that this shouldn't be recommended as that could introduce security vulnerabilities (SQL Injection) as the emulation is not flawless.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your note! Have you found a better solution instead of this trick? Thanks.

Comment: Most solutions suggest increasing the value of `table_definition_cache` in MySQL config.

Comment: Worked for me by increasing `table_definition_cache` from 400 to 1024 _(MariaDB 10.1.29)_.

Comment: As @David mentioned, `SET GLOBAL table_definition_cache = 1024` worked for me. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#table_definition_cache

Comment: Works on Laravel  5.6 :-)

Comment: Turning off the prepared statement emulation causes other bugs.  In particular, this one is a total show-stopper: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23850.  On PHP 7.2 floats are all rounded to integers when saving in mysql decimal fields.  It seems that until the bug is fixed in MariaDB, the only option is having table_definition_cache bigger than the total number of tables on the server (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17124).

Comment: this is the second time that this answer helped me and worked. is there any alternative solution for this? why @DanielHoward said this has risk. how can we solve without security risks?

Comment: This will work, but at the same time, It will convert all the integer values to string from select queries in your entire project.

Comment: Hi, in my case: `systemctl restart mysqld.service` fix the problem

Answer (score 23):

As per the comments in the accepted answer, 
running

`SET GLOBAL table_definition_cache = 1024`

in the MariaDB solved the problem.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#table_definition_cache

Comment: This bug seems to affect views in particular.  The bug has been submitted here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17124 and the MariaDB devs have got a patch for it.  Until that's rolled out, it seems from the discussion that table_definition_cache has to be set more than your total number of tables across all databases on the server (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;)

Comment: - This is the better solution.  The error only appers when use VIEWS .

- Doing the : \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true  on laravel ,we get another problem: 

- Int fields as returned like strings , and can be a problem with some JS / react, etc. 

- Setting SET GLOBAL table_definition_cache = 1024 , resolve the problem like a charm

Comment: this worked perfect, in my case. Thank you

Comment: this also works for me on mariadb and laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a [MySQL Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041) that has been documented.

**Edit:**

Is your model using 'id' as the primary key? I like to set the primary key explicitly in the model even if it is.

`protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // If different than id, definitely need to set the column here`

You can also try commenting out the `hasMany()` functions and trying again. Sometimes Laravel can do weird things on eagerLoad, especially if there are A LOT of records that it is trying to map to.

Comment: As wrote in the question, I already found that bug, but I have mariaDB (fork of MySQL) and I can't increase value of that property. Bug report was suspended.

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 Updated answer

Comment: thank you for you editing. No, it is not a primary key. Try it anyway but it doesn't work. I tried to comment `customersList()` and `issues()` methods and call `$s = Source::find(1);` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: What are your fillable columns? You may have reserved words or something else that is breaking the queries.

Comment: Can you post your table structure? Have you tried anything else since posting this? Any luck?

Comment: The sql view was made of 2 colums: id and name. It was created by a select on a table in another db. It was ok because the phpmyadmin's queries worked good and the php mysqli code inside the laravel project worked too. Now I trasformed the 2 db-view in 2 table and it work. But the problem is not closed.. Have you tried to query an sql view table with artisan tinker? Thanks